# Does helium freeze at absolute zero?

Tags: phase, noble-gases

Does helium freeze at absolute zero? In theory, it should, since all random motions of particles stops at absolute zero, right?

Comment: It actually doesn't. I'm not talking about ordinary pressures, I'm talking about absolute zero at any pressure.

Answer (score 3):

Not at atmospheric pressure.  You need at least 25 atmospheres pressure to solidify helium-4 and at least 29 atmospheres (0.3 K) for helium-3.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_helium).

At low pressure you fail to solidify the helium because of weak interatomic interactions combined with quantum mechanical zero point energy.  Higher pressure favors forming a denser structure with an ordered lattice arrangement, thus a crystalline solid.